# How do i execute my own routine while WIN API message loop is looping?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, api, loops

i've made a simple Window API application in VS C++, actually I'm showing the window, but I need to execute my process while Windows is executing its message loop. How could it be done ? Do in need to make it a multithreading process? Thank you in advance,

regards

Comment: _'Do in need to make it a multithreading process?'_ Probably yes, but this depends on the details of your actual use case.

Comment: Windows does not have a message loop.  Your program does.  You can tinker with it the way you want, replacing GetMessage with PeekMessage so you can execute other code is common, particularly in game loops.